# White page with Nginx Php-fpm and no errors logged

Tags: php, nginx, archlinux

I have a server running with archlinux, nginx and Php-fpm and when I try to load a page all I get is a white page.I've tried multiple fixes found on the internet but none have worked for me.

Here is my nginx conf file :

```
server {

listen  80; 

root /home/www-data/websites/subdomain.domain.net;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name subdomain.domain.net;

access_log /root/logs/nginx/subdomain.access.log;
error_log /root/logs/nginx/subdomain.error.log;

location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                  }

location ~* \ (gif|jpg|png) {
            expires 30d;
                            }

location ~ ^/favicons/.*$ {
            try_files $uri /data/$uri;
                          }

location / {
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri /public/$uri /index.php$is_args$args;
           }
}
```

The error logs of both nginx & subdomain.error.log are empty.

The file is located in /home/www-data/websites/subdomain.domain.net/index.php and contains the following :

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed a fresh debian install and everything works now